# Java Como usar correctamente un JProgressBar

Tags: java, date, progressbar, jlabel

**Buenas**

Estoy tratando de desarrollar una función en un botón que lee un archivo Excel y genera un Archivo .TXT formateado a gusto.

Mi problema es que quiero que se muestre en un JProgressBar la carga de los datos fila por fila, ademas mostrar en un JLabel el nombre del código que se esta leyendo en ese momento del archivo Excel, toda la función corre correctamente pero ni la barra ni el Jlabel se actualizan en tiempo real solamente la Barra se llena cuando se genera el .txt y el Jlabel solamente muestra el ultimo registro.

he utilizado la función  `Thread.sleep(5*1000);` entre filas del archivo Excel para pausar 5 segundos la función, pensando que no se muestra en pantalla por la rapidez del proceso ya que los archivos solo contienen 5 filas y 4 columnas, pero aunque hay una pausa en esa pausa tampoco se actualiza ni la barra ni el Jlabel.

Dejo el código que estoy usando para generar esto:

Librerías que estoy utilizando:

- commons-collections4-4.3
- commons-compress-1.18
- poi-4.1.0
- poi-ooxml-4.1.0
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.0
- xmlbeans-3.1.0

Por las dudas el contenido del archivo Excel es:

[image: Muestra del archivo Excel]

Dejo la función completa donde leo las columnas y genero el proceso:

```
    jProgressBar1.setMaximum(5);
        
    List<String> columnas = Arrays.asList("Name", "Size", "Type", "Condition");
               
    Map<String, Integer> mapNombresColumnas = new HashMap<>();
               
    final int filaNombresColumnas = 0;
        
     JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
     FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Excel files", "xlsx"); 
     chooser.setFileFilter(filter); 
     chooser.setDialogTitle("Open file"); 
     chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
               
     if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){ 
        String ruta1 = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();//.concat(".xlsx"); 
            
        File archivoXLSX = new File(ruta1); 

        try {
                
            XSSFWorkbook libro = new XSSFWorkbook(archivoXLSX);
                
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = libro.getSheetAt(0);
                
            Row filaNombresColumna = sheet.getRow(filaNombresColumnas);
                
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            Row row;
            row=filaNombresColumna;
                
            row.cellIterator().forEachRemaining(cell -> {
                
                String valorCelda = cell.getStringCellValue().trim();
                if (!valorCelda.isEmpty()) {
                    mapNombresColumnas.put(valorCelda, cell.getColumnIndex());
                }
            });
                
            int indiceDatos = filaNombresColumnas + 1;
            Row filaDatos = null;
                   
            int cont1 = 0, cont2 = 0;
                  
            int conteo = 1;
                  
            FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter("C:/Test/Result.txt");
                
            fichero.write("Results");
            fichero.write("\r\n");
               
            while ((filaDatos = sheet.getRow(indiceDatos++)) != null) {

                cont1++; cont2=0; 
                
                jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue() + 1);
                
                Thread.sleep(5*1000);
                
                String Text = "inicio"; 
                
                int cont = 1;
                
                for (String col : columnas) {
                        
                    cont2++;
                      
                    Cell celda = filaDatos.getCell(mapNombresColumnas.get(col));
                  
                    if(celda == null){
                  
                        Text = Text +"|Ninguno";
                  
                    }else{
                      
                        switch(celda.getCellType()){
                  
                            case STRING:
                          
                                String texto = celda.getStringCellValue();
                                //System.out.println(texto);

                                Text = Text + "|" + texto;
                
                           
                            break;
                           
                            case BLANK:
                          
                                Text = Text + "|";
                                
                            break;     
                           
                            case NUMERIC:
                          
                                int numero = (int) celda.getNumericCellValue(); 
                                String numeroString = Integer.toString(numero); 
                                Text = Text + "|" + numeroString;
                          
                            break;
                          
                            case FORMULA:
                        
                                switch(celda.getCachedFormulaResultType()){
                          
                                    case NUMERIC:
                                    
                                        int numero2 = (int) celda.getNumericCellValue(); 
                                        String numeroString2 = Integer.toString(numero2); 
                                        Text = Text + "|" + numeroString2;
                                  
                                    break;
                                  
                                    case STRING:
                                  
                                        texto = celda.getStringCellValue();
                                        Text = Text + "|" + texto;
                                  
                                    break;
                              
                                }
                          
                            break;
                          
                            case _NONE:
                          
                                System.out.println("NONE");
                          
                            break;
                          
                            default:
                          
                                System.out.println("nulo!!!");
                          
                            break;
                        }
                  
                    }
                  

                }
                    
                String Array[] = Text.split("\\|");
                    
                System.out.println(Text);
                 
                if(!Array[1].equals("Ninguno") && !Array[2].equals("Ninguno")){  
                  
                    jLabel1.setText(Array[1]);
                    
                    String conteoString = Integer.toString(conteo);
                    String conteoformateado = String.format("%14s", conteoString).replace(' ','0');
                    
                    fichero.write("Start+"+ conteoformateado +"+ISSDG10");  
                    fichero.write("\r\n");
                    
                    if(Array[4].equals("DMG") ||
                       Array[4].equals("dmg") ||
                       Array[4].equals("inoperativo") ||
                       Array[4].equals("INOPERATIVO") ||
                       Array[4].equals("inop") ||
                       Array[4].equals("INOP")){
                    
                        fichero.write("Fail+999");
                    
                    }else{
                    
                        fichero.write("Got+34");
                    
                    }
                    
                    fichero.write("\r\n");
                    fichero.write("Free+20++1++++");
                    fichero.write("\r\n");
                    fichero.write("LOCAL+9+");
                    fichero.write("\r\n");
                    fichero.write("INF+"+Array[1]+"+"+Array[2]+Array[3]+"+4");
                    fichero.write("\r\n");
                    fichero.write("C+10+"+conteoformateado);
                    fichero.write("\r\n");
                    
                    conteo ++;

                }
                
                if(Array[1].equals("Ninguno") || Array[2].equals("Ninguno")){
                
                    cont1--; 
                
                }
               
            }
                
            System.out.println("\r\n " + cont1 +"\r\n" + cont2); 
                
            fichero.close();
                
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Generate.");
                
        } catch (org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException ex) {
               
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
               
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            
            Logger.getLogger(jProgressBar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(jProgressBar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

**Actualización**

Estoy probando SwingUtilities lo que aparenta ser la solución a esto, pero de momento no logro aplicarlo correctamente a mi código, he modificado las siguientes lineas de código:

```
cont1++; cont2=0; 
                
                final int percent = cont1;
                
                 try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    updateBar(percent);
                  }
                });
                Thread.sleep(5*1000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              }
```

La función `updateBar`:

```
    public void updateBar(int newValue) {
    jProgressBar1.setValue(newValue);
  }
```

Comment: Cuando le pones un `Thread.sleep(5*1000);` paras toda tu ejecución del hilo actual, esa podría ser una de las causas. Yo mandaría la actualización del progress bar al hilo de gráficos de Java mediante `SwingUtilities`. Inténtalo y nos cuentas si te funciona o no. Saludos.

Comment: @RuslanLópez Muchas gracias, por lo que estuve viendo la solución esta allí, aun no logro aplicarlo correctamente en mi código pero ya actualice la pregunta