# El metodo Repaint() se ejecuta pero no pasa nada

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo el juego de snake y quiero que al presionar las teclas de movimiento se mueva la serpiente,

Cuando presiono una tecla:

```
private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    KeyCode = evt.getKeyCode();        

    if(!hiloInicia){
        if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP || KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){            
            this.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Así intento simular el movimiento:

```
int x = 94, y = 349;
int KeyCode;
boolean hiloInicia = false;    
boolean chocar = false;

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    
    g.fillRect(x, y, 40, 40);
}

@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        while(!chocar){
            switch (KeyCode){
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                    x = x + 40;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                    x = x - 40;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                    y = y - 40;
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                    y = y + 40;
                    break;                        
            }
            
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(500);                
        }   
    }catch(Exception e){
        
    }
}
```

AL presionar una tecla, por ejemplo la tecla RIGHT, x cambia su valor pero el metodo `repaint()` no funciona, aparte de eso, al intentar cerrar la aplicacion no me deja

Comment: eso pasa porque estas durmiendo el hilo entre ciclos, deberias delegarlo al hilo de dibujo mediante swingutilities, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414082/java-como-usar-correctamente-un-jprogressbar

Comment: Sin ofender, tu respuesta no me responde mucho, no se que tengo que hacer con swingutilities ni cual es la diferencia, quisiera que me dijeras como implementarlo