Cuando quiero pasar de un Jframe a otro frame que es una pantalla de carga, la barra de carga no funciona y no me deja acceder a las demás interfaces
En java netbeans,, tengo 3 JFrames, el primero es un login, el cual cuando se pone la contraseña correcta avanza al segundo JFrame una pantalla de carga, la cual muestra la barra de carga, y el tercero es un menú principal.
Cuando ingreso la contraseña correcta en el login y llega a la pantalla de carga, la barra de carga se queda en 0 y no avanza al menú principal.
Voy a dejar el código que tengo en la pantalla de carga, ya que mis demas interfaces tienen un código demasiado extenso:
package pk_Barra;
import pk_Interfaces.MenuPrincipal;
public class BarraCarga extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * Creates new form BarraCarga
 */
public BarraCarga() {
    initComponents();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Titulo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    barra_carga = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
    porcentaje = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Cargando = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);

    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    Titulo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Rockwell Condensed", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    Titulo.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(20, 30, 70));
    Titulo.setText("Bienvenido");
    jPanel1.add(Titulo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(250, 10, -1, -1));
    jPanel1.add(barra_carga, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(46, 90, 510, -1));

    porcentaje.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Rockwell Condensed", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    porcentaje.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(20, 30, 70));
    porcentaje.setText("0%");
    jPanel1.add(porcentaje, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 110, -1, -1));

    Cargando.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Rockwell Condensed", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    Cargando.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(20, 30, 70));
    Cargando.setText("Cargando...");
    jPanel1.add(Cargando, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(250, 50, -1, -1));

    jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/GarzaCarga.gif"))); // NOI18N
    jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 600, 500));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    BarraCarga car = new BarraCarga();
    


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        
        public void run() {
            car.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    
    MenuPrincipal men = new MenuPrincipal();
    try {
        for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
            Thread.sleep(40);
            car.barra_carga.setValue(i);
            car.porcentaje.setText(Integer.toString(i)+"%");
        
        }
    
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    new BarraCarga().setVisible(false);
    men.setVisible(true);
    car.dispose();
    
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel Cargando;
private javax.swing.JLabel Titulo;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar barra_carga;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel porcentaje;
// End of variables declaration                   

}

relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414082/java-como-usar-correctamente-un-jprogressbar
